# Cherrypy VirtualHost dispatcher not working

Tags: cherrypy

I've got the following in my cherrypy config, but /foo is not handling my request to http://foo.bar.com ... The cherrypy app is behind nginx which is passing the host header through - I'm outputting the Host header at / and it is returning 'foo.bar.com' so I'd expect /foo to handle this request.

```
[/]
request.dispatch = cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost(**{ 
    'foo.bar.com': '/foo',
})
```

Nginx is doing a proxy_pass to 127.0.0.1 with:

```
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem, but it seems to be an application vs global config problem. I was setting the VirtualHosts in server.cfg which was loaded into the global config and I was mounting without an application config:

```
cherrypy.config.update("server.cfg")
cherrypy.tree.mount(root, "/")
```

Setting the application config fixed the problem:

```
conf = {
  "/": {
    "request.dispatch": cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost(
      **{
        "foo.domain.com:8000": "/foo",
        "bar.domain.com:8000": "/bar"
      }
    )
  }
}
cherrypy.tree.mount(root, "/", conf)
```

If anyone wants to explain I'll accept their answer. I'm now wondering if any setting I put under [/] in server.cfg (cherrypy.config) will work correctly or if all path specific config needs to be in the application config.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the dispatcher from the global config, I do think that this is not obvious but the [dispatcher itself is responsible of handling the merging of the configurations](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/dispatching.html#configuration).

Another reason for confusion is that because if you use the `cherryd` command it might seem like is something normal.

For example you could deploy an application like this:

```
cherryd -c server.cfg
```

Having `server.cfg` as:

```
[global]
tree.app = myapp.root
[/]
request.dispatch = cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()
```

With the following implementation on `myapp.py`:

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        return "Hi!"

root = cherrypy.Application(Root())
```

But `cherryd` have a few trick under his wing.

One is the added namespace "tree" on which you set `tree.NAME_OF_APP = INSTANCE_OF_CHERRYPY_APP` and more importantly setting the dispatcher on the "global" configuration file works because the `cherryd` command merges the configuration file into the application when there is only one application mounted on the tree.

Something like:

```
cherrypy.tree.apps.values()[0].merge(config)
```

Effectively making the "global" configuration like a "local-per-app" configuration.